# Npc not moving to waypoints in order?

Tags: lua, roblox

Ive been trying to move an npc to a waypoint in order, it worked for a bit but then it starts moving out of order and is starting to act weird

Waypoints:
[image]

Move script:

```
for i,node in pairs(script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Cartnodes:GetChildren()) do
if node:IsA("BasePart") then
    print(node.Name)
    script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("Rafthuman"):MoveTo(node.Position)
    

    script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("Rafthuman").MoveToFinished:Wait()
    
    node:Destroy()
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unintuitively, the order of the children is not determined by alphabetical order. If you look at the docs for [Instance:GetGhildren()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetChildren), you'll see this note :

> The children are sorted by the order in which their Parent property was set to the object.

So to get them in the right order, you'll need to sort the list before iterating over it.

```
local raftHuman = script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("Rafthuman")
local nodes = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Cartnodes
local children = nodes:GetChildren()
local sortedChildren = table.sort(children, function(a, b) 
    return a.Name < b.Name
end)
for i,node in ipairs(sortedChildren) do
    if node:IsA("BasePart") then
        print(node.Name)
        raftHuman:MoveTo(node.Position)
        raftHuman.MoveToFinished:Wait()
        node:Destroy()
    end
end
```